# Response was: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

`SSRS` report deploy was successed but i got this error when i am trying to 
configure the mail for `SSRS` reports,

Error:

> Failure sending mail: The server rejected the sender address. The
>   server response was: 530 5.7.0  Must issue a STARTTLS command first.
>   l80sm65371449pfi.76 - gsmtp Mail will not be resent.

any body help me..

Comment: i did...just follow [link1](http://www.isolutionspartners.com/how-to-configure-ssrs-report-subscriptions-to-use-gmail-for-gp/) and [link2](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps/mail-settings/Sm16T9DPJ5Q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did...just follow [link1](http://www.isolutionspartners.com/how-to-configure-ssrs-report-subscriptions-to-use-gmail-for-gp/) and [link2](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps/mail-settings/Sm16T9DPJ5Q)